# How to show comma only once in tkinter calculator

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building tkinter python calculator. And I want to add comma button. But as we know comma appears in every calculator's window only once. I made a condition that makes that you can type only once but when you type other sign you can type more than one comma sign. How to do if condition that you can type only once in any case.

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter.ttk import *

root=Tk()

def show_point():
    if e.get()==".":
        pass
    else:
        e.insert(END,".")

e=Entry(root,width=30,justify="right",font=(None,20))
e.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3,ipady=10,sticky=W)
but19 = Button(root,text=".", style='my.TButton',command=show_point)
but19.grid(row=5,column=3,ipadx=10,ipady=15)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal example?

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: You're using the wrong terminology. The `.` is called a period, not a comma (which is `,`).

Comment: What is the comma for? and the Q seems quite unclear, could you explain to again?

Comment: Additional button in calculator to make decimal number like in many calculators

Comment: Whatever, user could only type `.` once or less.Right?

Comment: yes I want ot use it only once like in many calculators you use it only once

Comment: At any time the user could type `.` Do you really want a button.

Comment: I want for example to type in calculator for example 95.23 or 0.2312312, and then you don;t use it twice or more

Comment: quick fix: `if "." in e.get():`

Comment: Great it worked thanks man!!!

Comment: the answer: if "." in e.get():
        pass
    else:
        e.insert(END,".")

Comment: then when people press the key `"."` in the keyboard, your `show_point` doesn't work.

Comment: What you need here, i believe is a validation, to enter just decimals

Comment: That's what I was looking for when you type period or comma in entry you can't add more period/comma. That happens in most of ordinary calculators. But thanl you for help.

Comment: @Maria Keep in mind though, in my answer, the `100000000000000 ` represents the numbers you can enter, like 123456789123456.1231231....... After the decimal there can be infinite digits but before the decimal you can have `len(100000000000000)` digits. You can increase it, if you want more than 15 digits numbers

Comment: @Maria Hi, i know its over, but i found an easier way for my answer while encountering another Q here, ive updated my Q, take a look. Before there was a flaw, the person could enter spaces in between digits, now its fixed.

Comment: yeah of course thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what your looking for:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()

def correct(inp):
    if inp == '':
        return True
    if ' ' in inp:
        return False
    try:
        float(inp)
    except ValueError: #catching error because strings cannot be converted to string
        return False
    else:
        return True

reg = root.register(correct) #registering validation
e = Entry(root, width=30, justify="right", font=(None, 20),validate='key', validatecommand=(reg, '%P')) #assigning it while declaring
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, ipady=10, sticky=W)

#but19 = Button(root,text=".", style='my.TButton',command=correct)
# but19.grid(row=5,column=3,ipadx=10,ipady=15)

root.mainloop()
```

This is just validation, your allowing the user to just enter decimals, anything other than that will not be allowed at all.

[Take a look here for more info on validation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/entry-validation.html)

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Try that instead of the if statement

```
    input = e.get()
    try:
        input.index(".")
    except:
        e.insert(END, ".")
```

Comment: Ok but the thing is not to change a period to comma but when you use an ordinary calculator in pc or tablet or smartphone you can only type com or period once no matter what you type after. And the thing is how to write the statement that you use it only once.

Comment: @Maria Why did you accept this answer, if its not the correct one? xp

Comment: I finally accepted your's and gave eveeryone additional points for effort. I think someone finds his own solution

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need to something called "validation" which `Entry` widgets support. This will allow you to make sure the character isn't entered more than once (or any other rule you want to enforce), either by clicking on the `Button` or by manually typing it in. For reference see [Adding validation to an `Entry` widget](https://web.archive.org/web/20190524022302id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry-validation.html).

Here's how to do it in the context of what you're trying to do:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter.ttk import *

PERIOD = '.'

root = Tk()

def insert_point():
    if e.get().count(PERIOD) < 1:  # Allow at most one in entry.
        e.insert(END, PERIOD)

def check_okay(new_value):
    return new_value.count(PERIOD) < 2  # Only zero or one allowed in entry.

ok_command = root.register(check_okay)  # Register the callback function.

e = Entry(root, width=30, justify="right", font=(None, 20),
          validate='all', validatecommand=(ok_command, '%P'))
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, ipady=10, sticky=W)
but19 = Button(root, text=PERIOD, style='my.TButton', command=insert_point)
but19.grid(row=5, column=3, ipadx=10, ipady=15)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help