# How to pass a value to an entry validatecommand

Tags: python-3.x, validation, tkinter

I am validating a form in tkinter using `validatecommand`. There are two entries, one should only accept integers and the other floats.
Here is the basic code:

```
import tkinter as tk
class Form(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        validCmd1 = (self.register(self.val1), "%P")
        validCmd2 = (self.register(self.val2), "%P")
        self.lab1 = tk.Label(self, text = "Float:")
        self.lab1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        self.ent1 = tk.Entry(self, validate = "key", validatecommand = validCmd1)
        self.ent1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.lab2 = tk.Label(self, text = "Integer:")
        self.lab2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = (0,10))
        self.ent2 = tk.Entry(self, validate = "key", validatecommand = validCmd2)
        self.ent2.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    def val1(self, value):
        try:
            float(value)
        except:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    def val2(self, value):
        try:
            int(value)
        except:
            return False
        else:
            return True
app = Form()
app.mainloop()
```

Instead of writing two different functions for two very similar tasks, I tried to pass an integer to the validate command (1 for float, 2 for integer). I tried to use lambdas to pass values to the validation functions, first on the self.register part: `self.register(lambda: self.val1(1))` but this gave `TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given` and the second time I tried using lambda on the validatecommand command: `validatecommand = lambda: validCmd1(1)` which gives `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`.
Is it possible to pass values to a validation command?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63886059/how-to-show-comma-only-once-in-tkinter-calculator/63887260#63887260) help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `validatecommand` option takes a tuple that can have any arguments you want. For example, if you want to pass an integer it's as easy as this:

```
validCmd1 = (self.register(self.val), 1, "%P")
validCmd2 = (self.register(self.val), 2, "%P")

def val(self, arg, value):
    print(f"val1 arg='{arg}' value='{value}'")
    ...
```

Sometimes it's easier to understand if you separate the registration of the command from the value passed in to `validatecommand`. For example:

```
vcmd = self.register(self.val)
...
self.ent1 = tk.Entry(..., validatecommand = (vcmd, 1, "%P"))
self.ent2 = tk.Entry(..., validatecommand = (vcmd, 2, "%P"))
```

Comment: Does this limit the integer to be > 0? I seem to have an issue where it won't allow me to enter 0 when vcmd is set to %P.

Comment: @JayCroghan There is no limitation on the value being > 0.